# How to have a parent MDI form which is not the main form in an application

Tags: delphi, mdi

I'm trying to create a situation where I have a list of clients in a main form.

When i select a client, I want to be able to open a MDI parent window which can have various different MDI children.

It seems the VCL does not natively allow forms other than the MainForm to host MDI child forms.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround posted in QualityCentral:

[Hosting MDI child forms in non-MainForm forms](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=12006)

As well as on CodeCentral:

[Multiple MDI Parent Forms in a single Application](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23574)
(it is written in C++, though)

Comment: "please see QC's workaground, or download attach  workaround223782.txt 
it is too long to paste here" where is this?

Comment: @Danny, you must [`login to QC`](http://i.imgur.com/ZsuAfkl.png). It is not enough to be logged on to EDN (maybe to prevent more QC reports :-)